# Set TeXStudio as default software to open .tex files in Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: kubuntu, software-center, latex

On *Kubuntu* 15.04, I've installed the latest version of `TeXStudio`. However, when I click on a `.tex` file, it automatically compiles with `vprerex`.

> How do I set `TeXStudio` as default application to open `.tex` files?

Comment: Sorry, I read Ubuntu :') I canceled my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your system settings, there should be something like file assignment (I am not using English Kubuntu, but the icon should consist of 3 different diagonally arranged file symbols, and it should be in the uppermost block), if you click you can search for latex in the search field, then click on x-tex, or tex or whatever comes up, then sort texstudio to the top in the right field that appears when you click on "tex" from the list.